# Signal level shifting from +-15 to +-25

Tags: level-shifting

I have a bipolar signal with a peak to peak voltage of 30V (+-15V). I need to shift the signal level to be (+-25) with a dual supply voltage rails of (+-25). Do you have any ideas or a circuit implementation for such a task?
i need to use discrete components so i can reach a higher voltages, my signal is a square wave Bipolar 50% duty cycle and 40 kHz frequency

Comment: The square-wave frequency of 40kHz is a start but to get a decent solution you'll need to consider what rise times and fall times are acceptable and what load impedance the signal needs to drive - this information is definitely needed given you you may need quite fast rise and fall times.

Comment: Producing a signal of +-25V from a +-25V power supply is not possible, the will always be some voltage drop. Also, (as Andy has stated): describe your problem fully: input source impedance, output load, required waveform (rise and fall times, overshoot/ringing budget), allowed delay from input to output.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a bipolar signal with a peak to peak voltage of 30V (+-15V). I
>   need to shift the signal level to be (+-25) with a dual supply voltage
>   rails of (+-25). Do you have any ideas or a circuit implementation for
>   such a task?

The [LTC2057HV](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC2057) device can handle +/-30V supplies. It might be worth a look.

Input common mode range extends below the negative rail and within 1.5V of positive rail and it has rail-to-rail outputs.

You just need to configure it as a gain of \$\frac{25}{15} = 1.6667\$

Comment: Thanks Andy very much for the answer, unfortunately this IC is not available to me in the store, do you have an idea about circuit implementation using the normal power transistors

Comment: @Tarek what about the OPA547; in fact what is your supplier limits? Maybe you should explain the supplier problem in your question and also give a more detailed spec about signal frequencies/bandwidth and output current.

Comment: Dear Andy, away from the supplier problem, we can think on it in different way, with IC we still limited by the maximum driving voltage of the IC, i need to use discrete components so i can reach a higher voltages, my signal is a square wave Bipolar 50% duty cycle and 40 kHz frequency

Comment: @Tarek Then I suggest you modify your question so that your requirements are clear to anyone wishing to answer. You need to specify what load you need to drive too.